# Detect when the user's cursor stops using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to preload content when the user's mouse stops above a link. If the user's mouse rapidly moves across the page and stops on a link, I'm assuming that the user will click that link. Is there an easy way to detect this?

Comment: bind mouseenter event for the link.. maybe use a setTimeout as well.. if the mouseleave event if fired before the timeout, just clear the timeout..

Comment: Have you made any effort to try this?

Comment: http://richardscarrott.co.uk/posts/view/jquery-mousestop-event

Comment: What happens if the user doesn't click the link, do you unload the page ?

Comment: @adeneo The link is preloaded in the background using a prefetch. If the user doesn't click, then nothing happens aside from a bit of wasted bandwidth.

Comment: @putvande I thought about using `setInterval()` and calculating the rate of change, but that's pretty complex. I'm hoping for an easier solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("yourElement").hover(function () {
       // Do this when mouse is over element},
     function () {
       //  Optional.  Do this when mouse leaves element
 });
```

Comment: The problem with this is that if the user moves the cursor across the page, then many links will get preloaded.

Comment: What exactly are you loading when the user hovers over the links?  I don't advise it, but one option is to use setTimeout.  Generally, however, if you have to do something like that, you're thinking about it the wrong way.